Tensorflow model still trains even with training=False
Simple code to reproduce follows
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras as keras

inp = keras.Input((3, 3))
layer = keras.layers.Dense(1)
tar = layer(inp)

tar2 = layer(inp, training=False)
model2 = keras.Model(inp, tar2)
model2.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(0.01))

# fit
a = tf.random.normal((1, 3, 3))
b = tf.random.normal((1, 3, 1))

model2.fit(a, b)

If you check model2.trainable_variables before/after the training, you can easily check that parameters of the model2 have been changed which means it has been trained.
What should I do in order not to update the certain layer in certain time during training?
The reason why I need is, my scheme is to reuse some layers I made before and I don't want those layers to be trained again while I still update other layers in the model. Like follows:
inp1 = keras.Input((2, 3))
inp2 = keras.Input((4, 3))

layer1 = keras.layers.Dense(1)
intermediate_output1 = layer1(inp1)
intermediate_output2 = layer1(inp2, training=False) # I don't want to train this layer again for inp2.

added = tf.concat([intermediate_output1, intermediate_output2], axis=1)
layer2 = keras.layers.Dense(2)
final_output = layer2(added)
final_output.shape # [None, 6, 4]


You can freeze a layer with
layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(12)
layer.trainable = False

You can also do that for a model, and then all layers of that model are frozen.
model.trainable = False
model.layers[0].trainable  # -> False


With the method in your question you can force a layer to behave like it is always in training or always in inference for the forward pass. For most layers this does not change a thing, e.g. a Dense layer behaves the same in training and validation for inference. But e.g. a Dropout layer behaves different in training or outside. Normally, a dropout layer is disabled outside of training.
inp = tf.keras.layers.Input((12,))
drop = tf.keras.layers.Dropout()(inp, training=True)

In this example, you get a Monte Carlo Dropout layer. This is a Dropout layer that is always active, regardless of training or test time.

Well once you freeze the layer with layer.trainable = False it is not trainble with inp1 for above example. I did some research and found out that tf.stop_gradient() will be the answer. intermediate_output2 = tf.stop_gradient(layer1(inp2)).

Sorry I completely missed the point that you re-used layer1.. that makes my answer a bit useless. Glad that you found your soltion though!
